# how to download an uploaded blob file from google app engine using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I had uploaded a file as a blob store and stored in the Google app engine from this guide [Uploading file to Google App engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Complete_Sample_App). Now am trying to show the file name and when a user clicks on the file the corresponding file to be downloaded. I don't know how to download a blob file as originally how i uploaded. I tried up to this,

```
 Query query = new Query("__BlobInfo__");
 query.addFilter("filename", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, req.getParameter("name"));
 DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
 PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);
 List<Entity> entList = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1));
 if (entList.size() > 0) {
 BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(entList.get(0).getKey().getName());
 BlobInfoFactory bi = new BlobInfoFactory();
 String fname = bi.loadBlobInfo(blobKey).getFilename();
 if (fname.contains(".mp3") || fname.contains(".aac")) {
 res.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
 res.setHeader("Content-Type", "save as filename=" + fname);
```

but don't know how to handle after the above code. Kindly suggest me an idea

Answer (score 0):

See the function [serve](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#serve%28com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey,%20HttpServletResponse%29) of BlobstoreService. Also the overview has a section for [serving blobs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob).